# Sequentially nest vectors/list in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

How could I convert this:

```
[a b c d e]
```

or this:

```
(e d c b a) ;(rseq [a b c d e])
```

to this:

```
[a[b[c[d[e]]]]]
```

I've been wracking my brain and I feel like there is a simple solution! :-\

Ultimately I want to do this:

```
[a b c d e]
[a b c x y]
[a b c d j k]
```

as this:

```
{a {b {c {d {e}
            {j {k}}
         {x {y}}}}
```

Which I think conj will help with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Update: added answer to the new question added in the edit below the answer to the original question.)*

I've actually answered this very question in #clojure recently.

Here are two approaches: `f` is pretty much the spec directly transformed into code, which however creates a seq -- `(next xs)` -- which immediately gets poured into a new vector at each step; `g` is a much better version which only allocates objects which will actually occur in the output, plus a vector and the seq links to traverse it:

```
;; [1 2 3] -> [1 [2 [3]]]

;; naive, quadratic:
(defn f [xs]
  (if (next xs)
    [(first xs) (vec (f (next xs)))]
    (vec xs)))

;; only allocates output + 1 vector + a linear number of seq links,
;; linear overall:
(defn g [v]
  (reduce (fn [acc x]
            [x acc])
          [(peek v)]
          (rseq (pop v))))
```

NB. I'm overlooking the usual logarithmic factors arising from vector operations (so this is [soft-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Extensions_to_the_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) complexity).

---

As for producing a nested map, the above isn't particularly useful. Here's one approach:

```
(defn h
  ([v]
     (h nil v))
  ([m v]
     (assoc-in m v nil)))

(h [1 2 3 4])
;= {1 {2 {3 {4 nil}}}}

(def data
  '[[a b c d e]
    [a b c x y]
    [a b c d j k]])

(reduce h {} data)
;= {a {b {c {x {y nil}, d {j {k nil}, e nil}}}}}
```

I'm using `nil` as a "terminator", since `{y}` (as currently found in the answer text) is not a well-formed literal. `true` might be a more convenient choice if you plan to call these maps as functions to check for presence of keys.

Comment: Funny enough I like the naive approach as I think it's possibly more idiomatic, to me at least. I had a funny feeling reduce was a solution, I'm going to have to look in to peek and pop more closely

Comment: Going by the shape of the code alone, `f` and `g` are about equally idiomatic, with `g` having a possible edge in that it uses a well-understood library function (`reduce`) to drive the transformation, whereas `f` uses custom recursion. Taking semantics into account I'd only consider `g` idiomatic, since `f` uses completely the wrong data structures and transformations, contrary to the spirit of Clojure. As for complexity, `f` is quadratic, `g` is linear (overlooking the usual logarithmic factors resulting from vector lookups).

Comment: what is "(fn [acc x]
            [x acc])" actually doing?

Comment: It is taking two arguments, `acc` and `x`, and returning a vector with them in reverse order. (The first vector here is part of `fn` form syntax, the second vector is the only body expression.)

Comment: If the input is a vector and `subvec`s are used instead, would it still be true that `f` is doomed to quadratic? I haven't invested the behavior of stacking `subvec`s.

Comment: True, it wouldn't be quadratic then, but `subvec` produces "view vectors" which prevent the original from becoming eligible for GC. The version of `subvec` from [core.rrb-vector](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector) doesn't have this problem, but the vectors it produces are somewhat slower; this is OK if the fast slicing is a big win, but here we can just use `g`, no reason to accept a slowdown.

Comment: thanks for the map reduce example. I ended up using nil as well. trying to figure out how to put all this to use in my program now :)

Answer (score 4):

Simpler solution here (using destructuring and non-tail recursion):

http://ideone.com/qchXZC

```
(defn wrap
  ([[a & as]]
    (if-let [[b & cs] as]
      [a (wrap as)]
    [a])))
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Is there a benefit of tail recursion and non-tail recursion in clojure?

Comment: @scape Tail recursion doesn't push anything to stack and is faster. In Clojure, tail recursion can ONLY be done with `recur` special form.

Comment: I tried a loop/recur but ultimately couldn't figure it out, thanks for the info!